# How do I declare global variables in Pact lang?

Tags: pact-lang, kadena

I'm writing a smart contract and I want to declare global variables. I want the functions in my smart contract to be able to access and update these variables.

For example, in Solidity I can do this as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract SolidityTest {
   uint someSmartContractVar;      // State variable
   constructor() public {
      someSmartContractVar = 10;   // Setting the variable
   }

   ...

}
```

I see the coin contract makes use of [defconst](https://pact-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pact-reference.html#defconst) [here](https://github.com/kadena-io/chainweb-node/blob/master/pact/coin-contract/v5/coin-v5.pact#L148):

```
  (defconst COIN_CHARSET CHARSET_LATIN1
    "The default coin contract character set")
```

This approach is good for variables that need to be accessible by the rest of the contract, but I don't think I can change the values of these variables at some later point.

One possibility is creating a table named "global-variables" and storing the specific variables there. So then the functions can access and change these variables via table reads and updates. For example:

```
  (defschema global-variable-schema
    someSmartContractVar:decimal)

  (deftable global-variables:{global-variable-schema})

  (defconst GLOBAL_VAR_KEYNAME "global-vars")

  (defun constructor:string ()
    (insert global-variables GLOBAL_VAR_KEYNAME
          { 'someSmartContractVar: 10.0 }
    )
    "Global variables set"
  )

  (defun get-someSmartContractVar:decimal ()
    (at "someSmartContractVar" (read global-variables GLOBAL_VAR_KEYNAME))
  )
```

Is this the recommended approach for this type of use case?

Answer (score 0):

Great question and that solution should work!
I don't know of any other practical way to do it.